# Do Schläfli symbols unambiguously represent gemetric shapes?

Tags: notation, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry, stereographic-projections, tessellations

According to Wikipedia, the [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) is the four-dimensional analogue of the cube and has the [Schläfli symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) {4,3,3}, and Wikipedia features the following visualization:

[image: Visualization of the tesseract]

However, when looking at it, I wonder whether this could also be a [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of a tessellation of spherical 3-space (the analogue of [spherical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry) in three dimensions) using three cubes around every edge, from spherical 3-space to Euclidean 3-space (except the fact that the edges are straight in this image, whereas they would be bent in the stereographic projection), similarly to what the [icosahedral honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_honeycomb) {3,5,3} (which is a tiling of hyperbolic 3-space using the icosahedron) looks like in the [Poincaré ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model):

[image: Visualization of the icosahedral honeycomb]

So, my question is, does the Schläfli symbol {4,3,3} unambiguously represent the tesseract, or could it also represent a cubic tessellation of spherical 3-space that has three cubes around every edge? If it cannot represent this tessellation of spherical 3-space, does the tessellation have some other Schläfli symbol (in that case, what?), or can't spherical 3-space be tessellated in this way at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schläfli symbol only captures topology. You are right that this Schläfli symbol represents a cubic tessellation of spherical 3-space, but topologically there is no ambiguity here: the tesseract **is** that tessellation, just as the cube **is** a square tessellation of the sphere, or the square is a tesselation of the circle. (Yes, they are all finite.)

If you want to distinguish between tessellations of the $(n-1)$-sphere and polytopes in the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, you indeed have to specify this underlying geometry "manually".

Comment: I agree with you, almost: I would say that the (facets of the) _boundary_ of those shapes are tessellations of those spaces. But I get your point. I hadn't though about it like that before, or that it holds in all dimensions (I'm guessing that the facets of the boundary of an $n$-dimensional hypercube is a tesselation of $S^{n-1}$ for any $n\geq 2$?).